STM32H7 CortexM4 USART DMA issue
I'm trying to use USART  + RTS only + DMA(non circular, peripheral to memory, DMA1 Stram0) on STM32H755ZIT6's M4 processor.
My code is working on M7 but it does not works on M4 and I'm getting Framing Error , which means that the stop bit is not recognized on reception at the expected time
// u8* dma_rx_buffer_ = (u8*)((u32)0x24000000);
// u8* dma_rx_buffer_ = (u8*)((u32)0x38000000);
u8* dma_rx_buffer_ = (u8*)((u32)0x30000000);

int main(void)
{
    //SCB_InvalidateDCache_by_Addr((u32*)dma_rx_buffer_, 14);
    error = HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&usart2_dma_, dma_rx_buffer_, 14);
}

as you can see I'm setting RAM_D2's address to the dma_rx_buffer_, but I can't use SCB_InvalidateDCache_by_Addr on M4.
This is M7's Flash.ld
MEMORY {   
         RAM_D1 (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x24000000, LENGTH =  512K
         FLASH   (rx)   : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 1024K
         DTCMRAM (xrw)  : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
         RAM_D2 (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x30000000, LENGTH = 288K
         RAM_D3 (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x38000000, LENGTH = 64K
         ITCMRAM (xrw)  : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 64K
      }

this is M4's Flash.ld
MEMORY
    {
       FLASH (rx)     : ORIGIN = 0x08100000, LENGTH = 1024K
       RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 288K
       //RAM_D2 (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x30000000, LENGTH = 288K
       //RAM_D3 (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x38000000, LENGTH = 64K
    }

I also tried to add RAM_D1 and RAM_D2 inside M4's Flash.ld file and use it like this
`attribute ((section(".RAM_D2"))) attribute ((aligned (32))) u8* dma_rx_buffer_;
but no result.
I also read DMA is not working on STM32H7 devices, but can't find solution.
P.S all configurations, including DMA are correct .
Also when I'm setting different addresses for dma_rx_buffer_ then I'm getting different data.
Do I need to add MPU region for CortexM4?
Update: Configured MPU region accrding DRAM addresses, but no result, with RAM_D1, RAM_D2 or RAM_D3.
/* Disable fault exceptions */
SCB->SHCSR &= ~SCB_SHCSR_MEMFAULTENA_Msk;

/* Disable the MPU and clear the control register*/
MPU->CTRL = 0;

MPU->CTRL = MPU_PRIVILEGED_DEFAULT | MPU_CTRL_ENABLE_Msk;

SCB->SHCSR |= SCB_SHCSR_MEMFAULTENA_Msk;

__DSB();
__ISB();

MPU->RNR = MPU_REGION_NUMBER8;

//MPU->RBAR = 0x24000000;
//MPU->RBAR = 0x38000000;
MPU->RBAR = 0x30000000;
MPU->RASR = ((uint32_t)MPU_INSTRUCTION_ACCESS_ENABLE << MPU_RASR_XN_Pos)   |
            ((uint32_t)MPU_REGION_FULL_ACCESS << MPU_RASR_AP_Pos)   |
            ((uint32_t)MPU_TEX_LEVEL0 << MPU_RASR_TEX_Pos)  |
            ((uint32_t)MPU_ACCESS_SHAREABLE << MPU_RASR_S_Pos)    |
            ((uint32_t)MPU_ACCESS_CACHEABLE << MPU_RASR_C_Pos)    |
            ((uint32_t)MPU_ACCESS_BUFFERABLE << MPU_RASR_B_Pos)    |
            ((uint32_t)0x00 << MPU_RASR_SRD_Pos)  |
            ((uint32_t)MPU_REGION_SIZE_32B << MPU_RASR_SIZE_Pos) |
            ((uint32_t)MPU_REGION_ENABLE << MPU_RASR_ENABLE_Pos);

what I'm doing wrong?

Which clock source is driving the USART on the M4? Is it the same clock source on the M7? And which device is sending the data you try to receive?
Framing errors can be easily caused when the clock frequencies (baud rate) of the communication partners are not matching well enough.

The clock source for USART (M4) is HSI. Yes I'm using HSI on M7 too. (for spi and another usart). STM32F103 is sending the data. The baud rates are the same on both mcu.

What clock source is used on the STM32F103? Are you using exactly the same USART peripheral when running the code on M4 instead of M7? What is the peripheral clock used for the USART? Is it the same when running on the M7 and on the M4? I am still suspecting a clock configuration issue. The clock tree of the STM32H755 is quite staggering...

I did use different clock sources on M4 (HSI, PPL1,2,3 outputs) BUT it's always 64MHz.
The clock frequency on STM32F103 is also 64MHz, same baud rates and other USART configurations.

Those internal oscillators, such as HSI, have inaccuracies from part to part (or over temperature) than can make baud rates differ enough to cause communications errors.  It might be worthwhile to compare both devices' baud rates with an oscilloscope.  An external crystal can provide a more accurate clock source.

@kkrambo I tried an external crystal but did not help/
